# Mibs exception FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mibs.mps'

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming

I am using [Mibs](https://github.com/coin-or/MibS), a solver for mixed integer bilevel linear optimization problems. I am using it through the Python interface [PAO](https://pao.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) package. My bilevel program is kind of complicated, so I am not pasting it here. I will if it helps to clarify the questions.

So my question is the Bilevel program I implemented sometimes raiseFileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mibs.mps'. Is anyone familiar with this solver and knows what this means? The problem is this error does not happen all the time, but in some instances only. Each instance is determined by those non-decision variable parameters, and I am generating problem instances randomly.

One guess I have is maybe this error happens because the bilevel program does not have any feasible solutions. I was wondering if there are other possible reasons that might cause this error.